# How to resolve MongoDB returning nothing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Hello I am fairly new to MongoDb so I am busy practicing on how it works so I added some dummy data into the database so am I try making a get request and the response I am getting is an empty array which really does not make sense to me because I do have data within the database can I please get some assistance

Code Below is where I tried making the get request to the database:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const router = express.Router();

const mongoURI =
  "mongodb+srv://<MyUsername>:<MyPassword>@cluster0.hupbh.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&  w=majority";

router.get("/womens-clothing", (request, response) => {
  mongoose.connect(mongoURI, {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });

  const con = mongoose.connection;
  con.on("open", async () => {
    await con
      .collection("WomensClothes")
      .find()
      .toArray()
      .then((data) => {
        response.status(200).json(data);
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Data Successfully Fetched");
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: The collection name is case sensitive so please make sure that it exactly matches with what is there in DB

Comment: I checked that and made sure I type in the proper collection name